# Groupby().tranform() Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have created a data set in which I want to find the maximum Sale and name of the person

```
data={'Company':['GOG','GOG','FB','FB','LT','LT'],'Name':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],'Sales':[200,120,340,124,243,350]}

data_s=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(data_s)
```

Will print the below DataFrame

```
Company     Name        Sales
0   GOG     A          200
1   GOG     B          120
2   FB      C          340
3   FB      D          124
4   LT      E          243
5   LT      F          350

s=data_s.groupby('Company')['Sales'].transform(max)==data_s['Sales']
data_s[s]

Company Name    Sales
0   GOG A   200
2   FB  C   340
5   LT  F   350
```

My question is how can apply the lambda function to solve this or is there any other alternative method?

Comment: Solve what? What is the problem with your attempt? Please describe situation and post desired result.

Comment: As mentioned I need the name of the employee and the company he works for, with the maximum sales. I have solved the problem using one method, was asking if there is an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `idxmax` to get the index of the max value and use that index to look up the row you are interested in:

```
index_of_highest_sale = data_s.groupby('Company')['Sales'].idxmax()
person_details = data_s.loc[index_of_highest_sale]
```

Comment: But that gives the person with the highest sales not the person from each company with highest sales

Comment: You can do that by grouping by company as well (see updated answer)